# XML Serialization and class aliasing? Possible?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dotnet-httpclient

I am using a HttpClient and making a GetAsync call.  I am then making sure the call is successfuly by calling `response.ErrorSuccessStatusCode()`.

I then call `response.Content.ReadAsAsync<WikiResponse>()`.  I am getting an error when ReadAsAsync is called because the 3rd party REST service is passing back and XML response called "Response" instead of "WikiResponse."  This WikiResponse was created by yet another 3rd party.  I can't create an object called just Response because there is already a class named this at the same "level" as the other DTOs but with a different class structure.

Is there a way to get WikiResponse to "fit" into the Response?  The XML and Classes structure are identical EXCEPT for the Class name.

Thanks for the quick reply!

**UPDATE:**

I have tried using `[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Response")]` on the class, but it didn't work.

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException] = {"Error in line 1 position 103.  Expecting element 'WikiResponse' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Project.WikiResponses.DTO'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'Response', namespace 'http://www.someurl.com/url'. "}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of the overloads for ReadAsAsync:

```
public static Task<T> ReadAsAsync<T>(
    this HttpContent content,
    IEnumerable<MediaTypeFormatter> formatters
)
```

and create your own MediaTypeFormatter.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh943959(v=vs.108).aspx